# What prevents us from reconstructing PIE "u̯" by analogy with laryngeals?

Tags: phonetics, proto-indo-european

The current laws for laryngeals presume the following reconstruction rules:

- ē is reconstructed as eh<sub>1</sub>
- ā is reconstructed as eh<sub>2</sub>
- ō is reconstructed as eh<sub>3</sub>
- word-initial e- is reconstructed as h<sub>1</sub>e
- word-initial a- is reconstructed as h<sub>2</sub>e
- word-initial o- is reconstructed as h<sub>3</sub>e

Why we cannot reconstruct u̯ the same way? **ū** would be reconstructed as eu̯ and the word-initial **u** as as u̯e.

Thus:

- The word for **wolf** would be *u̯elq<sup>u̯</sup>os*;
- The word for **wheat** would be *peu̯ros*;
- The word for **son** would be *seu̯nos*.

Why not?

Comment: Are there any phenomena which such an analysis would make easier to explain? If not, Occam's razor suggests the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, [u] and [w] (i.e. u̯) are just allophones in PIE, so the only consequence of reconstructing **w-* as **we-* will be that it forces you to come up with some theory of why the following **-e-* was lost. Plus it doesn't really make sense. If you wanna get rid of word-initial **w-* by reconstructing it as **we-*, you'll notice that **w-* is still initial. So now you need to reconstruct **we-* as **wee-*, **wee-* as **weee-* etc. ad infinitum.

More importantly, we don't reconstruct **w-* as **we-* and **ū* as **ew* because there are lots and lots of examples of PIE **we-* and **ew* that didn't become **w-* and **ū*.

Comment: Do you support the idea that PIE had long ū?